# Couchbase Server services Where do they reside?

Tags: couchbase, bucket

Where do the Couchbase Server services reside? In the server, or inside a Bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Server](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.1/architecture/services-archi-multi-dimensional-scaling.html#concept_v4w_zmj_vs)

When you add a node [you define the services it performs](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.1/clustersetup/adding-nodes.html#topic_ncd_gdg_q4)

Only nodes with the data service can hold bucket data

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks for helping me!